# Настройка модуля EditDocs на MODX EVO3

Tags: modx

Установила модуль editDocs на MODX EVO3, но во вкладке редактирование при заполнение полей и клике по кнопке "Выполнить" - выскакивает красный попап в правом верхнем углу страницы: "Ошибка!Проверьте фильтрацию".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, может кто с таким сталкивался?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в неустановленном пакете pathologic/modxapi, а именно:
файл в папке core/custom назывался composer.json.example, необходимо было его переименовать в composer.json, а затем добавить в него в раздел require "pathologic/modxapi": "*", а уже после запустить composer update из папки core.